# F12 (GoToDefinition) doesn't do Reflector Decompile

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, .net-reflector

### Issue

**Steps to replicate**

- Install Visual Studio 2012
- Install Resharper
- Install Reflector VS plug-in

When I hit F12 I want the Resharper GoToDefintion (decompile) action.  However, all I get is the standard VS GoToDefinition (metadata).

### Things I've Tried

- Uninstalling Reflector
- Uninstalling Resharper
- Installing Reflector
- Messing with Keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you would like to use ReSharper "Navigation to Sources" feature, follow these steps:

1. Check F12 is mapped on ReSharper Go to Declaration action (ReSharper_GotoDeclaration) here Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard;
2. Check "Navigation to Sources" is selected here ReSharper | Options | Tools | External Sources.

Comment: I appreciate this, but I prefer Reflector's decompile over ReSharper's.  Thanks for the intel though i might end up having to do this if I can't find a solution to the current situation

Answer (score 3):

In my case the following simple steps helped:

1. Open *Resharper* -> *Options*
2. Navigate to *Tools* -> *External Sources*
3. Select *Default Visual Studio navigation*
4. *Save*